# Visualize community composition paired data

Tags: multivariate-analysis, paired-data

I have a data set where community composition data was collected from 2 sites in a paired design: under the canopy and nearby canopy.
We used mvabund package in R to check whether the communities differed. They do differ. The main problem is to find a way to plot the data and show that communities are different, **accounting for the paired design**. We plotted the data through nMDS, but the communities did not seem to be different at all.
I'm trying to use boral package but I haven't found in any example how to control for the pairing (blocks).

Comment: How did you measure "community composition"?

Comment: I have a matrix of species (columns) per samples (rows). Cells are filled with species abundances

Comment: Have you considered a simple side-by-side barchart or tornado diagram?

Comment: how would you account for the pairings in such situations?

Answer (score 1):

The updated version of BORAL allows for inclusion of site effects, which you can group as needed (replicates, nested, blocked, etc). See examples from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/boral/versions/1.7/topics/boral.

You can use results from BORAL in ggplot to create a figure similar to NMDS (using latent variables as axes), to show community differences.